# Radio button group validation. Highlight all unchecked radiogroup buttons questions with alert Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

**How can I achieve radio group validation**

`onClick` submit button it should highlight the radio group or question which is not answered with red color or some kind of validation.

For example onClick submit button if the any of the radio group buttons are not selected change ListGroupItem bsStyle="danger" to the particular list.

**ORIGINAL CODE *https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ujmlcz***

```js
//array of cards coming from the backend
const data = [
  {
    cardName: 'Do you want  sugar in your coffee',
    options: [
    { radioName: 'Yes',radioValue: '1', selected: false },
    { radioName: 'No',radioValue: '2', selected: false }]
  },
  {
    cardName: 'Do you want  milk in your coffee', 
    options: [
    { radioName: 'Yes',radioValue: '1', selected: false },
    { radioName: 'No',radioValue: '2', selected: false }]
  },
  {
    cardName: 'Do you want  low-fat-milk in your coffee', 
    options: [
    { radioName: 'Yes',radioValue: '1', selected: false },
    { radioName: 'No',radioValue: '2', selected: false }]
  }
];


class CardsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
cards: [],

    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // mimic an async server call
      this.setState({ cards: data });
    }, 1000);
  }

  onInputChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { cards } = this.state;
    const nexState = cards.map(card => {
      if (card.cardName !== target.name) return card;
      return {
        ...card,
        options: card.options.map(opt => {
          const checked = opt.radioName === target.value;
          return {
            ...opt,
            selected: checked
          }
        })
      }
    });
    this.setState({ cards: nexState })
  }

  onSubmit = () => { 
  let unselectedCards = this.state.cards.filter((card) => {
   return !card.options[0].selected && !card.options[1].selected
});
    console.log("Please answer all the questions"+unselectedCards);
    
 console.log(this.state.cards.map(({ cardName, options }) => {
  const option = options.filter(({ selected }) => selected)[0]
  return ` ${option.radioValue}`
}))
  };

 onReset = () => {
        this.setState({cards:[]});
      }
  render() {
    const { cards } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          cards.length < 1 ? "Loading..." :
            <div>
              {cards.map((card, idx) => (
                <ul>
                  {card.cardName}
                  {card.options.radioName}

                  {
                    card.options.map((lo, idx) => {
                      return <input
                        key={idx}
                        type="radio"
                        name={card.cardName}
                        value={lo.radioName}
                        checked={!!lo.selected}
                        onChange={this.onInputChange}
                      />

                    })
                  }
                </ul>
              ))
              }
              < button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Submit</button>
               < button onClick={this.onReset}>Clear</button>
            </div>
        }

      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CardsList />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you will first need to extend your state model. Consider tracking your "bsStyle" in each card by adding the following:

```
const data = [
  {
    cardName: 'Tires are inflated and free of excessive wear or damage.  Nuts are tight.',
    style : 'info', // <-- this is your bsStyle tracked for each card
    options: [
      { radioName: 'Yes', radioValue: '1', selected: false },
      { radioName: 'No', radioValue: '2', selected: false }]
  },
  ...,
  ...
]
```

This allows your component to know about, and render, the appropriate bsStyle for each card idenpendantly. With this, you can now update your `onSubmit` function by adding the following "validation" functionality:

```
  onSubmit = () => {

    this.state.cards.forEach((card) => {
      // If no option in the card is selected, consider the card invalid
      var invalid = card.options.every(option => !option.selected)
      if(invalid) {
        card.style='danger'
      }
      else {
        card.style='info'
      }
    });

    // Cause form to re-render to display "danger" or "info" bsStyle
    this.setState({ cards : this.state.cards })

    ...
    ...
 }
```

You'll also want to ensure validation is updated when the user changes input. You could achieve that by the following:

```
  onInputChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { cards } = this.state;
    const { options } = this.state;

    const nexState = cards.map(card => {
      if (card.cardName !== target.name) return card;

      const options = card.options.map(opt => {
        const checked = opt.radioName === target.value;
        return {
          ...opt,
          selected: checked
        }
      })

      const style = options.every(option => !option.selected) ? 'danger' : 'info'

      return {
        ...card,
        style,
        options 
      }
    });
    this.setState({ cards: nexState })
  }
```

Lastly, you'll want to update the way your rendering of `ListGroupItem` works by making the following adjustment:

```
{cards.map((card, idx) => (
    <ListGroup bsStyle="custom">
        <ListGroupItem bsStyle={ card.style }>
        ...
        </ListGroupItem>
    </ListGroup>)}
```

For more detail, you can find a complete working example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-immp6b?file=index.js

Comment: if I  select answer (yes or no) after the danger style how can I change card style back to info style?

Comment: Hi, please see updated answer as well as updated code sample at https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-immp6b?file=index.js

Comment: You're welcome - looks like you're making great progress :-)

Comment: Sorry keep on troubling u again. Can u tell me best resource to learn react/ javascript. I am new to this field. From where should I start.

Comment: Hey, no need to apologise - I found the official react docs to be quite good, and MDN for general JavaScript + learning. If you get really stuck though, feel free to contact me directly (via website listed in my profile)

Comment: Thank u mate. i owe you. :)

Comment: Hey mate. How can I Auto scroll to the next question. For example if user answer first question then it scroll to the second question. How can I achieve that.

Comment: Probably best to answer this in a new question - happy to do so if you set that up :-)

Comment: I made new post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886547/automatically-scroll-down-to-next-listgroup-item-and-display-the-content-in-cent)